# PowerShell: After renaming AD Object, Move-Mailbox cannot locate object

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

So in my script, when a user changes their name, I rename their AD object accordingly, change their Exchange (2007) properties, and then based on those changes, I change the info store that it is in.

I store the new DistinguishedName in $newDN when retrieving the mailbox, explicitly try to use DC01.domain.local, and then when I attempt to do the move, it tries searching on DC02.domain.local, therefore not finding the object due to replication lag and receive this error below.  Anyone have any ideas on this?  Many thanks!

StatusCode : -1056749240
StatusMessage : Error occurred in the step: Approving object. Failed to open object 'LDAP://DC02.domain.local/CN=di matteo\, robert,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=local' with error: There is no such object on the server.

```
$mailbox = Get-Mailbox -ID $newDN `
    -DomainController DC01.domain.local

$mailbox | Move-Mailbox `
    -TargetDatabase $targetIS `
    -Confirm:$False `
    -DomainController DC01.domain.local `
    -GlobalCatalog DC01.domain.local
```

Sometimes the move works, but when it doesn't, it leaves the SourceDomainController property empty (like below), where as if it does work, it populates it correctly with DC01.domain.local.

```
SourceServer                     : CCR.domain.local
SourceDatabase                   : CCR\IS1\IS1
SourceGlobalCatalog              : DC01.domain.local
SourceDomainController           : 
TargetGlobalCatalog              : DC01.domain.local
TargetDomainController           : DC01.domain.local
TargetMailbox                    : 
TargetServer                     : CCR.domain.local
TargetDatabase                   : CCR\IS2\IS2
```

Baffled.

Comment: Is it possible to simply add a while loop something like: while(!$newUserObject -and !$timedOut){...(try to get the newUserObject and see if it's been too long since we started.. and sleep for 10 seconds between loops)...}

Comment: @ChrisN Yeah, could have done that, but I really wanted to get down to the issue of why it wouldn't use the explicitly stated Domain Controller.  Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've got no idea why I'm getting the results that I am, but my workaround is here...Like I said before, I query/write all my AD changes to 'DC01.domain.local' But now, when I call my function, I do my mailbox lookup on 'DC02.domain.local'.  If the lookup fails, increment the counter, sleep for about 20 seconds, and then retry.  My initial testing, it has only had to loop once.

```
$dc = "DC01.domain.local"

Function moveDB ($targetIS, $newDN, $counter) {

$dn = (Get-Mailbox -ID $newDN -DomainController $dc).DistinguishedName

If (!(Get-Mailbox $dn -DomainController "DC02.domain.local")) {
    $counter++
    If ($counter -le 4) {
        Write-Host "`nPlease wait while I search for the mailbox object...`n"  -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
        moveDB $targetIS $dn $dbCounter
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "Mailbox was not moved!  Please move manually to $targetIS..."  -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Red
        return
    }
}
Else {
    $dn | Move-Mailbox `
        -DomainController $dc `
        -GlobalCatalog $dc `
        -TargetDatabase $targetIS `
        -Confirm:$False
    }
}
```